# How to remove strike marks from Imported Objects

Tags: pimcore

why I am getting strike marks on imported objects after importing through csv file and how to remove it

Comment: That's probably because they're in the "unpublished" state after importing.
You can publish them by either opening them and click the "publish" button in the header section, or by opening the folder. There's a checkbox in the object list indicating if an object is published or not.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to add some screenshots to @GNi33 's comment.

**Method one** is to right-click on an object and choose `Publish` from the context menu:

[image: Publishing a pimcore object]

**Method two** is using the batch functionality. This is very helpful when publishing several objects. Just left-click on the object folder and select all objects:

[image: Select all objects]

Then click on that little arrow in the head of the `Published`-column and choose `Batch change selected`:

[image: Batch change selected]

Finally just click the `Published`-checkbox in the modal and hit `Save`:

[image: Publish and save]

E voila, all objects inside that folder are published.

Comment: Thanks Stephan for u r answer